# Public/Private Subnet Architecture on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am having trouble understanding [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html) image:

[image]

Specifically what I want to have is the Global Accelerator attached to every region, with each region having a VPC and Load Balancer. Then in each AZ in a region, have a public and private subnet. The private subnet or database servers will do all the computation and rendering. The public subnet is the Load Balancer (or does the public subnet need to be a set of instances?).

The public subnet also has an Internet Gateway and NAT Gateway attached. The docs say a private subnet can access the internet using a NAT Gateway in the public subnet, but I don't understand why it doesn't just use the Internet Gateway.

I have a route table in the public subnet, and the private subnet. In the public subnet, the route table goes to `0.0.0.0/0` pointing to the internet gateway. In the private subnet, it goes to `0.0.0.0/0` pointing to the NAT gateway.

There are also an Elastic IP associated with the NAT Gateway, presumably so that's what the internet sees when I make a request from a private server.

My question is, what is connected to what? The docs aren't clear enough on a practical example. I would like to have a public subnet, which I think doesn't require having any instances (am I wrong?), only the load balancer. Then the private subnet is the computation/database subnet which *does* consist of instances which can only connect to the internet through the load balancer connected to the NAT gateway.

I am confused. I have read the docs over and over again but still don't see how this is supposed to be wired up. Any help explaining what is connected to what in this diagram (extending it to include the Global Accelerator) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you use global accelerator your ALB and instance can be private as shown [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/accessing-private-application-load-balancers-and-instances-through-aws-global-accelerator/). Not sure if this is what you are after?

Comment: Oh great, yeah that's what I'm after!

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind I can provide an answer with more info.

Comment: Yes please, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please don't take this the wrong way, but I don't think you really need everything you are saying that you want.

I would recommend that you start with one region and no Global Accelerator. Implement your system and either creating a test platform that can simulate user traffic, or release your system to your customers and monitor it to determine performance.

- If you run in multiple regions, you have a problem with **where to keep your data** -- data might be kept separate in each region, or replicated. This all depends upon your needs. I suggest you start simple, then expand if you need to operate differently.
- <s>Global Accelerator does not make sense when using multiple regions, since it is designed to send traffic to one location. Instead,</s> consider **Amazon CloudFront** to cache data closer to your customers to provide better performance.
- If your application runs on multiple web servers, put a Load Balancer in public subnet(s) and everything else in private subnet(s).

Put simply, **start simple**. Get your application working in the simplest possible way. Then, if you have greater requirements (eg low latency to users), look at adding Amazon CloudFront. Very few applications span multiple regions, so make that choice carefully and have a specific reason for doing so.

Comment: "Global Accelerator does not make sense when using multiple regions" I thought the whole point of global accelerator was to do anycast and support multiple regions (like Google Cloud).

Comment: If I have a load balancer in public subnet, do I need _instances_ in the public subnet? Or can I put all instances in the private subnet?

Comment: Oops! You are quite correct! Global Accelerator is listed as useful for multiple regions. I do suggest that you have a very good reason for using multiple regions before doing so. They introduce a lot of complexity that your application might not need.

Comment: By default, you should put _everything_ in private subnets for better security. However, _something_ needs to go in the public subnet to 'receive' traffic. If you are using a Load Balancer, then it would go in the public subnet. If you just have a single web server with no Load Balancer, then the web server would go in the public subnet. Theoretically, you could put everything in the public subnet and just protect resources with Security Groups, but multiple layers of protection are normally recommended for better security.

Comment: Cool, so the public subnet doesn't need any instances, I've been wondering that!

Answer (score 1):

When you use AWS Global Accelerator, you can keep your **ALB and instance private**, without exposing them to the internet.

Such architecture is explained in the recent AWS blog post:

- [Accessing private Application Load Balancers and EC2 instances through AWS Global Accelerator](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/accessing-private-application-load-balancers-and-instances-through-aws-global-accelerator/)

In this architecture, **internal ALB** is used, and there are **no public subnets**. The only requirements is the pretense of internet gateway in the VPC. It should be noted, that even though there is internet gateway, no routes are configured for the subnets to access the internet:

> To avoid internet traffic from inadvertently flowing into a private subnet, we require that an internet gateway is attached to the VPC that contains resources when a client address-preserving accelerator is created.

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of the internet gateway then, if it's not attached to any routes or anything except the VPC? It seems like it is a hack because of their code or something :)

Comment: What do I need to do with the ENIs, do I create those or is that done automatically?

Comment: @LancePollard "To avoid internet traffic from inadvertently flowing into a private subnet, we require that an internet gateway is attached to the VPC that contains resources when a client address-preserving accelerator is created." The ENI should be created by the accelerator in the subnets you specify. I don't have all possible answers :-(

Comment: Another question this brings up is if you need a NAT Gateway still in this system.

Comment: @LancePollard Its app your application. NAT gateway is used for your instances to access internet, but nothing from internet can access the instance. Thus your instances will require updated, installation of software or external APIs than NAT will be required. But for NAT you also need a public subnet. So your VPC will need to have at least one such subnet.

Answer (score 0):

I came in late but:

One rule is "if it can stay in private subnet then keep it in private subnet". Accessing the internet will always be costlier. When that is done if you must reach the internet then use VPC endpoints (if possible) instead of NATG and IGW. Endpoints are cheaper and make cheaper data transfers.

For Accelerator and Cloudfront, if data cacheing will be a pain for you then use Accelerator, if not, simply put, CloudFront is cheaper and better.

Despite all this, your architecture and use case will always decide your best and cheapest set up.